# How can I Know about SD card logs (eject or mount details) in Android logs?

Tags: sd-card, logging

I want to maintain a log of when the SD card is ejected or mounted in my Android device. How can I do this?

Comment: Please don't Capitalize Every Word in your question.

Comment: I'll take care next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That could e.g. be done using [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker):

- **Condition:** Event → Hardware → Card Mounted
  <sup>(resp. "Card Removed" / "Card Unmounted")</sup>
- **Task:** File → Write File
  <sup>(specify file name, text, check "append")</sup>

You will need a separate profile for each action (mount/eject) with the respective condition, but of course you can write to the same file (or use a separate one if you prefer).

For details on *Tasker*, please check with our [tasker tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info).

Comment: Anytime! If it solves your issue, please don't forget to mark it such (using the check-mark next to the answer). Makes it easier for others to identify "solved issues" ;)

Comment: i don't want to do it with the help of an application . isn't there any other solution

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible without an application. Though there might be other apps to do it.